# How to make two ScrollViews synchronously scroll simultaneously on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two **ScrollViews**. When I scroll one the other should also scroll.

I tried using **onScroll** event, but it has a delay, the second **ScrollView** scrolls after a while. I really need it to scroll exactly at the same time.
Is there any other way to do it?

```
let scroll_ref_1 = null;
let scroll_ref_2 = null;

const Page = () => {
    
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <ScrollView
                ref={ref => scroll_ref_1 = ref}
                horizontal
                onScroll={e => {
                    if(scroll_ref_2 !== null) {
                        scroll_ref_2.scrollTo({
                            x: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x,
                            animated: false,
                        });
                    }
                }}
            >
                ...
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView
                horizontal
                ref={ref => scroll_ref_2 = ref}
            >
                ...
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a similar effect if you use flatlist with 2 columns.